# Android studio, как вернуться к последнему коммиту в git

Tags: android-studio, git

Писал программу и в один определенный момент у меня вдруг Android Studio перестала распознавать путь к ресурсам "import example.R;".

Я попытался удалить изменения, которые делал перед последним коммитом, но эта бесконечная индексация не прекращалась...

Я решил вернуться к последнему коммиту, перетыкал во вкладке VCS много всякого, но так и не понял как это сделать (до того как полез в VCS, на всякий случай копирнул весь проект).

Пожалуйста расскажите как через Android Studio вернуть весь мой проект к последнему коммиту в git? Чтобы весь проект вернулся к тому виду, когда я делал этот последний коммит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Решение:**

Вижу в вопросе, что вы не делали комит, если также вы не добавляли измененные файлы в индекс командой `git add`, то можете воспользоваться командой:

```
git checkout -- .
```

Эта команда делает откат изменных файлов к их исходному состоянию, т.е. состоянию когда не было совершенно каких либо изменения.

**Теория:**

Откуда Git узнает, на какой ветке вы находитесь в данный момент? Он хранит специальный указатель, который называется HEAD (верхушка).

- **git reset** - обновляет индекс, перемещая его на HEAD.
- **git checkout** - обновляет рабочую ветку. HEAD будет обновлен в случае, если вы делаете переход с ветки на ветку.

**О главном:**

Необходимо понимать что вы хотите получить после ввода команды. Более детально описано здесь - [ссылка на статью](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-reset).

Comment: Да, коммит я не делал и git add тоже.
А куда прописывать эту команду нужно? Просто ни разу не использовал их, всё делаю через интерфейс Android Studio.

Comment: "git checkout -- ." - использовали?

Comment: Нет, хочу его попробовать использовать, но не знаю куда прописывать эту команду.

Comment: Если вы работаете в Android Studio внизу есть вкладка Terminal.

Comment: Да, туда сейчас прописал "git checkout -- ." но ничего не произошло

Comment: git status набрали?

Comment: Нет. Можете сказать полностью что нужно прописать?

Comment: В терминал вводите сначала: git checkout -- .

Comment: Вывело Your branch is up to date with 'origin/doit'.
"doit" - название моей ветки рабочей

Comment: ну а git status наберите там же, посмотрите, есть список измененных файлов, красным выделен?

Comment: ну или просто в код залезьте и посмотрите, где вы последний раз писали, есть те изменения или нет

Comment: Просто сложно сказать есть ли изменения, потому что я уже сам поудалял всё, что было у меня до коммита, пытаясь решить проблему с невидимостью ресурсов ("R"). 
Ввёл команду git status и вывело: "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77183/discussion-between-timur-mukhortov-and--).

Answer (score 1):

git checkout -- . (эту команду прописывать в Terminal и произойдет откат к последнему коммиту)
Проблему с ресурсами решил "Build -> Clean Project", после этого R стало видно.

Comment: Необязательно было возвращаться к прошлому коммиту, чтобы решить проблему с ресурсами. Она может возникнуть на ровном месте даже без изменения кода.

Comment: Да, я это уже понял. Просто думал, что я что-то нечаянно сделал и уж лучше вернусь к последнему коммиту, т.к. сделать то, что я сделал после коммита, мне не составит труда. Но в след раз конечно сначала буду "Build -> Clean Project" делать

Answer (score 1):

Внизу в АС есть окно Version Control. В нем есть вкладка Log. Там все коммиты. Выделяете мышкой нужный, правая кнопка - Reset. Будут предложены разные варианты. Если нужно просто вернуться к прошому коммиту без сохранения изменений, то выбирайте Hard.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(картинка из интернета)

Это средствами Андроид Студии. Если делать через командную строку `git итд`, то для этого АС не нужна и можно делать в обычной консоли.